# Kill a process running inside a dockercontainer from a script

Tags: docker

I have s script do set up docker container in an automated routine, looking like:

```
...
sh 'docker run -d -t -p 1624:1624-v /home/somefolder/:/home/somefolder/ --name MyContainer--network myNetwork image:2.8
sh 'docker exec MyContainer npm config set proxy http://myProxy:8080'
sh 'docker exec MyContainer npm install'
...
```

Inside those container I need to execute some commands, and run processes. My problem is that I need to kill them afterwards automated again, without accessing the container manually or executing additional commands. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: You start the process with access to container, but when kill these process you do not want to access the container? What's the scenario?

Comment: my bad, i described it poorly. I do not want to access the container manually

Comment: Your script still can get the pid of these process in container through `exec`, and still could kill them through `exec`, what the `manually` mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for half a day, I found a working solution to that. If anyone else needs the Solution:

```
docker exec MyContainer myProcess.exe & sleep 120 && kill $!
```

It starts `myProcess` in the container, lets it running for 120 sec and kills it afterwards